# Dynamically generate table using PHP

Tags: php, formatting, html-table

I know this has been asked before and I have got it working using the following code:

```
<?php
$maxcols = 8;  $i = 0;
echo "<table id='table1'><tr>";

foreach ($id as $k => $v) {
    echo "<td id='0'><div id='{$k}' class='drag t1'>{$v}</div></td>"; $i++;
    if ($i == $maxcols) { $i = 0; echo "</tr><tr>"; }
} $i++;


while ($i <= $maxcols) {
    $i++; echo "<td></td>";
}

echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

This results in a table that looks like this :

[image]

I'd like to add headers to this so the end result looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to do it dynamically so if I create a table that is only 5 columns wide I'd get on the first header row ID01 - ID05 and on the second header row ID06 - ID10

I want to limit the header ID values to be no more than **$maxid** any extra header fields should be blank, like this : If **$maxid = 12;** then :

[image]

I need the header rows are made as follows and not using `<TH>`

```
<td class="mark">
```

I'm using some javascript to allow the movement of cell data.

The class is used to set the formatting on the header and stop items from being dragged into the fields.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you.

```
$maxcols = 8; 
$maxid = 12;
$startid = 1;

echo "<table id='table1'>\n";
for ($i = 1;$i<=ceil($maxid/$maxcols);$i++) {

    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$maxcols;$j++)
        if ($startid <= $maxid)
            echo "  <td class='mark'>ID".$startid++."</td>\n";
        else 
            echo "  <td> </td>\n";

    echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$maxcols;$j++)
        echo "<td>Content</td>\n";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";
```

Generates

```
<table id='table1'>
    <tr>
        <td class='mark'>ID1</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID2</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID3</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID4</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID5</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID6</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID7</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='mark'>ID9</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID10</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID11</td>
        <td class='mark'>ID12</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should add similar condition like `if ($startid <= $maxid)` in second for loop also to print only content for cells having header.

Comment: Something similar but that condition will not work because in the first loop $startid will reach $maxid and last Content row will not show at all.

Comment: Thanks for this - how do I edit `echo "<td>Content</td>\n";` to include the cell ID number as well ?  `eg : echo "<td id='ID12'>Content</td>\n";` ?

Thanks

Comment: This works. `echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    for ($j=1;$j<=$maxcols;$j++)
    $p = ($i==1) ? $j : ($j+$maxcols);
        echo "<td id='$p'>Content</td>\n";`

Answer (score 1):

try this. It will work in the same way as you desired

```
<?php

$id= array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");

$maxcols = 8;  $i = 0;$j=0;$t=0;$s=0;

$maxid = count($id);

echo "<table id='table1'><tr>";

foreach ($id as $k => $v) 
{

    if($t == 0)
    {

        while ($t <= $maxcols-1) {
                if($s < $maxid)
                {
                         $s++;$t++; echo "<td class='mark'>id$s</td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<td class='mark'></td>";$t++;$s++;
                }
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    else
    {

    }
        echo "<td id='0'><div id='{$k}' class='drag t1'>{$v}</div></td>"; $i++;
        if ($i == $maxcols) 
    { 
        echo "</tr><tr>"; 

        if($j == 0)
        {
            while ($j <= $maxcols-1) {
                if($s < $maxid)
                {
                     $s++;$j++; echo "<td class='mark'>id$s</td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<td class='mark'></td>";$j++;$s++;
                }
            }
            echo "</tr><tr>";

        }


        $i=0;

    }
} 

echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE59f.png)

Comment: Thanks, The DIV ID seems to be one less than the ID..

`<td id='0'><div id='5' class='drag t1'>6</div></td>` ? I was expecting it to be the same ?

Comment: @user214292  does your key of array start with `0` and value start with `1`. if yes then make `id='{$k}'` to `id='{$k+1}'`

Comment: I was using the example you posted which should start at 1.

Comment: yes, in my example values start from `1` where as keys of array start from `0`. i am assigning keys as id to `div's`. So you can also change the id to `$v` instead of `$k` which will result in same ids

Comment: @user214292   check here after changing div id from `$k` to `$v` it works fine  http://3v4l.org/RYQY8 Also `id='{$k+1}'` is invalid. sorry for incorrect info

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can Use My Library:

```
class generate{
private $row = "<tr>{columns}</tr>";
private $td = "<td {attr}>{data}</td>";

private $attributeTR="";
private $attributeTD="";

private $tdBuilder="";

public function addCol($ColumValsArr=array("class='motota'"=>"Example")){
    foreach($ColumValsArr as $key=>$val){
        $newCol = str_replace("{data}",$val,$this->td); 
        $newCol = str_replace("{attr}",$key,$newCol);

        $this->tdBuilder .= str_replace("{data}",$key,$newCol); 
    }
}
public function getRow(){
    return str_replace("{columns}",$this->tdBuilder,$this->row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function TableFunc($Data)
{
    $Table = "<table>" . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($Data as $tags => $array) {
        $Table .= "<$tags>" . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($array as $thead) {
            $tag=$tags==="tbody"?"td":"th";

            $Table .= "<tr>" . PHP_EOL;
            if (is_array($thead)) {
                foreach ($thead as $theadItem) {
                    if (is_array($theadItem))
                        $Table .= "<$tag colspan='$theadItem[1]'>$theadItem[0]</$tag>" . PHP_EOL;
                    else
                        $Table .= "<$tag>$theadItem</$tag>" . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
            $Table .= "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $Table .= "</$tags>" . PHP_EOL;
    }


    $Table .= "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

    return $Table;
}

$Data = array(
    "thead" => [
        [["GENEL BİLGİ", 2], ["KALORİMETRE (ISINMA)", 2], ["HESAPLAMA", 2]],
        ["NO", "AD SOYAD", "FARK", "TUTAR", "OKUMA", "ÖDENECEK"]
    ],
    "tbody"=>array(
        array("1","MURAT DURAN","100","100.00","10.00","110.00"),
        array("1","MURAT DURAN","100","100.00","10.00","110.00"),
        array("1","MURAT DURAN","100","100.00","10.00","110.00"),
        array("1","MURAT DURAN","100","100.00","10.00","110.00"),
    ),
    "tfoot" => [["NO", "AD SOYAD", "M2", "MAHSUP", "SAYAÇ", "15°", "FARK", "TUTAR", "ORTAK ALAN", "EKSTRA", "MUAFİYET", "OKUMA", "ÖDENECEK"]]
);



echo  TableFunc($Data);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its education explanation.  Please do not simply dump snippets on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).